# Importing openCV module into Android Studio project

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, import

I am trying to import openCV module using Import Module and selecting /Users/apple/Downloads/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/java. I am getting below error when I hit next button and Android Studio tries to sync:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':openCVLibrary300'. > failed to find target with hash string 'android-14' in: /Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk <a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>.
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going to the Android SDK manager and donwloading the api with the number 14 , And for further use you should download all versions so problem like these wont occur